# Magento filter productCollection by a specific tag

Tags: magento

I need to make a custom filter on productCollection based on a specific tag.
So let's assume I have the following productCollection:

```
<pre>
$collection_featured_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addCategoryFilter(Mage::registry('current_category'))
->addAttributeToSelect('*')     
->addAttributeToFilter('featured_product', 1);
</pre>
```

OR productCollection from products list page:

```
    $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('location');
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

How can I add to filter by a specific tag to get all the products containing that tag.
If i cannot filter in productCollection maybe i can do a join with tag table?! Please give example if true.

PS: if you need. I have Magento ver. 1.5.0.1

Thanks in add.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tagId = 3;  //Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->loadByName($tagName)->getId();

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addTagFilter($tagId);

print_r($products->getData());
```